# Getting the name from another table with an id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models with two corresponding tables: ReferralRequest and Gender. In the ReferralRequest table I store integer ids for gender named patient_gender_id and preferred_gender_id. The ids come from the genders table. I want to be able to call something like ReferralRequest.last.patient_gender.name to return the string from the genders table rather than the integer id from the referral_requests table, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong? All help appreciated for this rookie. Thanks!

ReferralRequest

```
class ReferralRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :gender
  has_many :referral_request_concerns
  has_many :concerns, through: :referral_request_concerns
  has_many :referral_request_insurances
  has_many :insurances, through: :referral_request_insurances
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 20 }
  validates :patient_gender_id, presence: true
  validates :preferred_gender_id, presence: true
end
```

Gender

```
class Gender < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :referral_requests
end
```

and corresponding tables:

```
  create_table "referral_requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.integer  "patient_gender_id"
    t.integer  "preferred_gender_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_referral_requests_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_referral_requests_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "genders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

Comment: You need explicitly tell Rails to use a different FK(`patient_gender_id`) as mentioned by Sachin R in his answer. If not Rails will look for `gender_id` by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@gender = Gender.find(ReferralRequest.last.patient_gender_id)
```

or

```
class ReferralRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient_gender, :class_name => "Gender", :foreign_key => "patient_gender_id"
end

@gender = ReferralRequest.last.patient_gender.name
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin! This makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `ReferralRequest.last.patient_gender.name` because you don't have a patient_gender column in your database table. You can call `ReferralRequest.last.patient_gender_id`.